# Why do I have to verify payment when downloading a free app?

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

I've downloaded free apps in the past without requiring verification. But now it makes me verify. Why? Can I turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple reasons that this may happen. Of late, it has been happening to users who have a credit card registered or have family sharing registered. If you go to iTunes and AppStore in settings, there will be an option to turn off verification for free apps. If credit cards are the cause, change the payment option to none and turn off family sharing.